# Can't dismiss MPMoviePlayerViewController when Home Button or Power Button pressed

Tags: ios

Basically, I have a **MainViewController** that presents a **MPMoviePlayerViewControllerExtended** and I want to dismiss **MPMoviePlayerViewControllerExtended** when user taps the Home Button or Power Button.

I tried this in MPMoviePlayerControllerExtended.m:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear {
     [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
}
-(void)viewDidDisappear {
     [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
}
```

But it doesn't work, apparently they aren't called when Home or Power button is pressed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both methods aren't called, I had to use Notifications.

In **MPMoviePlayerViewControllerExtended.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                          selector:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:) 
                                          name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification                  
                                          object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `:(BOOL)animated`

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
     [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
     [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
}
```

Also probably want to include the

```
[super viewWillDisappear:animated]
```

and

```
[super viewDidDisappear:animated]
```

in those somewhere too

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
     [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
     [super viewWillDisappear:animated]
}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
     [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
     [super viewDidDisappear:animated]
}
```